# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1+a_n}{1+x_na_n}=\lim \inf x_n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$ with $a_i\geq 0$. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{1+a_n}<\infty $.Then show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1+a_n}{1+x_na_n}=\lim \inf x_n$ for each real sequence $x_n$ with $x_i\geq 0$  .

How should I proceed?

Comment: Just put $x_{2n}=0$, $x_{2n+1}=1$ and $a_n>0$ to show it is false.

Comment: Or how about just $x_n =0$?